# How to decipher

Tags: cipher, steganography

I received the following challenge as a homework problem. Not much info is provided with it, except for the word Decrypt! at the end.

This problem is online on a password protected school site. So I cannot post the link. (No-one without an account would be able access it.)

This is for a course based on cryptography/network security

[image]

A hint I received said that I should look into the html code. Which is pasted below. I noticed the "nbsp;" tag repeats quite often, and exactly 57 times, which is also the name of this challenge in the URL code ie.. www.website.com/challenge/#57.html

So based on the hint to look into the html and the #57 in the url I believe it is possible this &nbsp tags are what to focus on.

Any help or clues on how to solve this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is only quote from https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Cities

Comment: You are onto something with the non-breaking spaces, but they are only half (well, 47.5%) of the story ...

Comment: @MOehm did you realize the answer? I wasn't sure if I should post given that it appears to be a homework assignment.

Comment: (I'm not sure why you keep removing the information from the puzzle that is needed for others to solve it. This site is not here *only* to serve you; please be considerate of those who haven't seen it yet, or who perhaps will find this in the future, and want a chance to solve it themselves. Removing the actual text with nonbreaking spaces from the puzzle renders it unsolvable—it's vandalizing your posts, which isn't actually allowed. Please don't do this.)

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to ask Are you *allowed* to ask that problem here? And is it a part of an ongoing competition etc.?

Comment: A dog man style 'un. Tale of two kitties by Dav Pilkey has something similar...

Comment: @Rubio should there not be some sort of issue raised any time one of these homework problems is posted? I feel like doing someone’s homework is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: yes, please delete this, as I do not feel comfortable with the answer being spelled out for me. I will be more careful next time, and state in my post that I do not want a whole answer

Comment: @El-Guest See [Should homework be allowed?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6121) on our Meta.  There is no overwhelming consensus on what our policy should be, so we really don't have one. My personal feeling is that we aren't here to do people's homework for them, but if someone shows the effort they've put in and asks for help, we can and should give them enough of a nudge in the right direction that they can figure it out for themselves. Having said that, if someone were to dress up their homework as a puzzle so we solve it for them, well, it's their own learning they're harming.

Comment: @anonymous You've already seen the answer; deleting it won't unring that bell. We generally avoid deleting content once it's been answered. If your concern is that someone might find the text here and believe a person in the class is being academically dishonest by getting the answer without doing the work themselves, I dunno, I feel like since that's actually what happened, it would be *more* dishonest to cover it up like it didn't happen. At least you can, honestly, say you only asked for "Any help or clues on how to solve this" rather than asking for the solution outright.

Comment: ok, fair enough, a learning experience for next time!, and well I hope it won't be easy to find for other students using google. Wouldn't want to wreck it for the whole class by finding the answer spelled out.

Comment: @Rubio thanks for the comprehensive answer. I don’t think it was anonymous’ intent to receive the entire answer but — and I’m sure I’ve been guilty of this at some point in the past — I think we should be more cognizant as a community of being aware of the level of guidance that is requested for these homework type puzzles. Perhaps some sort of identifier is useful for such a purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing simple spaces with 0 and non-breaking spaces with 1, we obtain:

> 010100000110000101110011011100110011101001100101011011100110001101110010011110010111000001110100001000000110100101110100

Splitting it 8 digit by 8 and converting [binary to UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=bin), we obtain a 15-character phrase:

> 01010000 P
>
> 01100001 a
>
> 01110011 s
>
> 01110011 s
>
> 00111010 :
>
> 01100101 e
>
> 01101110 n
>
> 01100011 c
>
> 01110010 r
>
> 01111001 y
>
> 01110000 p
>
> 01110100 t
>
> 00100000 <space>
>
> 01101001 I
>
> 01110100 t

You can also convert using on-line automatic tools like [this one](https://codebeautify.org/binary-string-converter).

Comment: This is a great answer (and gets a +1 from me), although I'm not sure how I feel about this homework assignment being answered for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it but May I delete sensitive info from the answer? I forgot to say that I just wished for a hint into the right direction, as this is a school homework problem.